# How to get Prolog to display a list

Tags: prolog

```
university(a60, 'Anglia Ruskin University', 'Eastern', 14200, 'www.anglia.ac.uk').
university(b22, 'University of Bedfordshire', 'Eastern', 9900, 'www.beds.ac.uk').
university(e14, 'University of East Anglia', 'Eastern', 10500, 'www.uea.ac.uk').
university(e70, 'The University of Essex', 'Eastern', 14450, 'www.essex.ac.uk').

program(computer_science, a60, graduate).
program(computer_science, b22, graduate).
program(computer_science, e14, undergraduate).
program(computer_science, e70, undergraduate).
program(math, a60 , graduate).
program(math, b22, graduate).
program(math, e14, undergraduate).

recommend_university(UcasCode, Degree, Location, TuitionLower, TuitionUpper, Program, University) :-
    university(UcasCode, University, Location, Tuition, Website),
    program_offered(UcasCode, Program, Degree),
    Tuition >= TuitionLower,
    Tuition =< TuitionUpper.

program_offered(UcasCode, Program, Degree) :-
    university(UcasCode, _, _, _, _),
    program(Program, UcasCode, Degree).

query_university :-
    write('Please enter the location: '),
    read(Location),
    write('Please enter the tuition range lower bound: '),
    read(TuitionLower),
    write('Please enter the tuition range upper bound: '),
    read(TuitionUpper),
    write('Please enter the program of study: '),
    read(Program),
    write('Please enter the level of study (undergraduate or graduate): '),
    read(Degree),

    recommend_university(UcasCode, Degree, Location, TuitionLower, TuitionUpper, Program, University),

    write('The recommended university is: '),
    write(University), nl;

    write('Sorry, there are no recommended Universities').
```

I am trying to get the system to recommend a list of universities based on criteria and display the list of universities matching the criteria.

However, after entering your preferences, the program moves straight to display 'Sorry, there are no recommended universities'. This message should only appear when there are no universities that match the criteria

Comment: Which preferences did you enter?

Comment: eastern, 900, 90000, math, graduate

Comment: `eastern` isn't `'Eastern'`